# Compute on report and count(decode( ))

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Can anyone here explain to me the breakdown of this code so I can better understand it:

```
COMPUTE SUM LABEL TOTAL OF "xxx" ON REPORT
```

It is my understanding that I am computing the sum, calling it total, of the column labeled "xxx", which will display the total at the bottom of the column, but what is throwing me off is the ON REPORT part.  What does that mean?

Also:

```
COUNT(DECODE())
```

This bit of code is throwing me off, too.  Thank you for reading my questions and thank you in advance for any explanations!

Comment: Perhaps this can help -- No expert on this though: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12014.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The syntax for the decode function is:
>
> decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [,default] )
>
> ***expression*** is the value to compare.
>
> ***search*** is the value that is compared against expression.
>
> ***result*** is the value returned, if expression is equal to search.
>
> ***default*** is optional. If no matches are found, the decode will return default. If default is omitted, then the decode statement will return null (if no matches are found)

I found this information at [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php).  I found it extremely helpful, so I thought I would share!  This, in combination with what sgeddes provided, which is a link to the Oracle documentation on the COMPUTE command found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12014.htm), answers my question.